# Covariance function of MA(1) process

Tags: covariance, moving-average

probably answered before but I would I want to see if my reasoning is correct, as my textbook skips the calculations but the answer coincide.

Q: Let $Z_t \sim \text{WN}(0, \sigma^2)$ (white noise), and define the MA(1) process $X_t = Z_t + \theta Z_{t-1}, t\in \mathbb{Z}, \theta \in \mathbb{R}. $ Find the covariance function $\gamma_X(t, t+h)$.

Sol: $E(X_t) = 0, E(X_t^2) = \sigma^2(1+\theta^2)$. Then

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\gamma_X(t,t+h) &= Cov(X_t, X_{t+h}) = E[(X_t - E(X_t))(X_{t+h}-E(X_{t+h})] \\ 
&= E(X_t X_{t+h}) = E[(Z_t + \theta Z_{t-1})(Z_{t+h} + \theta Z_{t+h-1}
)] \\
&= E(Z_tZ_{t+h}) + \theta E(Z_t Z_{t+h-1}) + \theta E(Z_{t-1} Z_{t+h}) + \theta^2 E(Z_{t-1}Z_{t+h-1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $Z_t$ is white noise, it holds that $\gamma_Z(s,t) = E(Z_s E_t) = \sigma^2 \delta(s-t)$. Hence

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\gamma_X(t,t+h) &= \sigma^2\delta(h) + \theta \sigma^2\delta(h+1) + \theta \sigma^2\delta(h-1) + \theta^2 \sigma^2 \delta(h) \\
&= \begin{cases}
\begin{split}
 &\sigma^2(1+\theta^2), \quad &h = 0 \\
&\sigma^2 \theta, \quad &h = \pm 1 \\
&0, \quad &\text{else}
\end{split}
\end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Your title should be edited -- it is MA(1) process, not AR(1) process.

Comment: Thank you, fixed it.

Comment: Your solution looks great.